# Scanning text to find domain types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to piece together a part of a create action in a controller that scans the the text entered and intelligently understands what type of domain name it is.

I have a text box called "domain_names". A user puts domains into the box separated by commas, e.g. "yahoo.com, google.com"

In the controller it hits it like this:

```
@extracted_domains = (params[:domain_names]).split(",")
@extracted_domains.each do |domain|
    domain.strip
    domain_scan = domain.scan(/(\w+)[.]/).flatten
    com_scan = domain.scan(/[.](\w+)/).flatten
    new_domain_type = DomainType.find_or_create_by_domain_type(:domain_type => com_scan)
    new_domain = Domain.create(:domain => domain_scan, :domain_type_id => new_domain_type.id)
end
```

In the console it works great. But when I put it into practise I get really odd things stored in the database. For example if :domain was meant to have the value "google", it will instead have the value  "---\n- google\n" , when its stored in the database.

No idea why

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE**

Problem: It was putting an array into a string.

Solution: Make it a string.

```
domain_scan = domain.scan(/(\w+)[.]/).flatten.first
com_scan = domain.scan(/[.](\w+)/).flatten.first
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your issue, can we see the exact params that are sent?

I would take a look at https://github.com/pauldix/domainatrix for domain extraction.

Comment: I had a look at that gem. It looks like a very good solution to my problem. But before I use it I want to figure out why this is happening. I want to do more similar things with non domain strings. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: jamie_gaskins: is right, it does seem like you are storing yaml. are you serializing the attribute - as when you do that is the default format.

Comment: As far as I know I'm not. Or at least not intending too. Is there any way around this? How do I convert it into a normal string? Thanks again, you are very helpful.

Comment: After some thought, I really should use that gem, simply because of the way that links can formatted differently; my code only works for "google.com", but if someone wrote www.google.com, it would probably break. If there are any further tips of how to convert it from yaml I would appreciate it - but for now let me mark this as the right answer to the problem :)

Comment: depends on your version of ruby/yaml parser but try YAML::load(  domain)

Comment: Hi Matthew, Sorry for not getting back sooner. It works for me on the console but doesn't help me in the controller. Should I change my ruby/yaml parser? It seems to be converting it when its saved in the db. Thanks again :).

Comment: Got the solution! - Just in case you were wondering. Thanks again from before.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be fed YAML input. Three dashes at the beginning of the string followed by a newline are a strong indicator of YAML: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Sample_document

Comment: Is there anyway to convert it? Thank you for your help.